# Samsung Galaxy 5 Driver for App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Will App Inventor work with Samsung Galaxy 5? Or do I need other drivers for it? I already have the App Inventor Setup.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does work , just change your settings as per

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/setup/phone.html

though samsung phones are not on list, i've seen it work smooth on samsung galaxy S

also if u want to install an application into your phone, just copy the .apk file to your phone and it gets it installed..

Answer (score -1):

It will work, just make sure you allow your device to allow apps downloaded from unknown sources, otherwise it won't allow you to download your app because it isn't from the play store